# Unable to start android app on phone 2.2.2 (higher ver App boot is ok)

Tags: android

When I try to run my App by HTC phone(ver 4.0.4) my App don't have any problem, but when I use REGZA (ver 2.2.2) it's cannot boot.

```
10-31 08:54:27.430: I/ActivityManager(158): Process *package name* (pid 29204) has died.
10-31 08:54:27.440: W/InputManagerService(158): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@3075bec0
10-31 08:54:27.460: I/UsageStats(158): Unexpected resume of com.android.settings while already resumed in *package name*
10-31 08:54:27.460: I/BootReceiver(158): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
```

I don't know where is this problem, if anybody have any ideas please share your idea for me.
Thanks.